# Check if autorepeat is enabled

Tags: linux, keyboard

For the purposes of an app I'm developing, I need to temporarily disable autorepeat (with `xset r off`), and then restore it back to its original state. Can I easily (like with a terminal command) check if it is on or not? I wouldn't want to `xset r on` indiscriminately in case the user had disabled autorepeat on their own before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if xset q | grep -q 'auto *repeat:  *on'; then ...
```

Comment: Guess I missed the `q` option in `man xset`, thank you.